# How to find the drive letter of Tomcat installation in Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, java-io

My webapp is running from Tomcat, installed on a Windows machine. I want the servlet to find out the drive letter (eg. C: or D: etc) programmatically, on which my Tomcat is installed.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the installation directory of an application.
you can search the registry
see [read/write to Windows Registry using Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

I uses [jregistrykey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jregistrykey/).

Answer (score 0):

First you need a place where a *ServletContext* is present. That might be a Servlet, ContextListener, Filter or maybe a JSP. Than, you can use this to find the root of the current drive:

```
File dir = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(""));
while (dir.getParentFile() != null) {
    dir = dir.getParentFile();
}
System.out.println("Current root directory: " + dir);
```